# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I use the delegate I created?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I will try to explain what is the problem:

I have one `UITabBarController`, it contains four `UIViewController`**(HomeViewController, HistoryViewController, SettingsViewController, InfoViewController)**, which the second one is `UINavigationController` **(HomeViewController -> ChattingViewController)**.

I have these :

```
@protocol DataManagerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void)StartRequestingData;
-(void)SuccessfulGettingData;
-(void)ErrorGettingData;
@end
```

And I have a Singleton class named "DataManager", it is used for making ASynchronousRequest.
And "DataManager" also has three "DataManagerDelegate" method.
They are :

In my BaseTabBarController.h, I have implemented these three method (always check if there is new data on server), which when I Successful Got Data (if there is new data), it will change the Image of Button in the TabBar.

And also I implemented those three method in ChattingViewController.

After I run the Application, all the thing is working fine. I selected the HomeViewController, and push to ChattingViewController.

The problem occurs when push back HomeViewController from  ChattingViewController.
It shows the error in DataManager.m where I activate that three delegate function.

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and relevant code.

Comment: Probably your delegate is getting deallocated. always check if(delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:aSelector]) before sending any message to it.

Comment: You don't need the `self.delegate &&` bit...

Comment: I think I have figure out the problem. I have to ask that if I implemented those three delegate method in my four UIViewControllers, when I activate those three methods in DataManager, all the three methods in four UIViewcontrollers will work at the the same time or those methods only work in one of the UIViewControllers ?